# Go BigQuery package installs with errors (Go version 1.10.1)

Tags: go, google-bigquery

For some reason, I get the following errors when installing the `cloud.google.com/go/bigquery` package. I'm a Go noob, so I assume I'm doing something wrong. I was wondering if anyone was able to replicate, or could point me in the direction about how to resolve these errors? For example, is using a `bool` type in place of a `*bool` legal in prior versions of Go? Perhaps this is a bug in the Google package?

```
$ go get -u cloud.google.com/go/bigquery

# cloud.google.com/go/bigquery
gocode/src/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/query.go:166:22: cannot use true (type bool) as type *bool in assignment
gocode/src/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/query.go:168:22: cannot use false (type bool) as type *bool in assignment
gocode/src/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/query.go:199:15: cannot use qq.UseLegacySql (type *bool) as type bool in field value
gocode/src/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/query.go:200:22: invalid operation: ! *bool
```

Comment: I also facing the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like someone pushed a broken change to the Go BigQuery client last night.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/commit/c718c274c122d2ca258bb8f93830d820cbb2160d

Should be fixed now. However, if you're using [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) for Go dependency management, it looks like you'll need to set the revision like so in `Gopkg.toml` (if you are trying to use [v0.21.0](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/tree/v0.21.0) of the `GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go` client):

```
[[constraint]]
  name = "cloud.google.com/go"
  revision = "c718c274c122d2ca258bb8f93830d820cbb2160d"
```

Sad times.